# Heroku.bat cannot run start

Tags: git, heroku-toolbelt

I suddenly ran into problem trying to run heroku toolbelt command within Git Bash.

```
$ heroku config
/c/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/bin/heroku.bat: line 9: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/c/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/bin/heroku.bat: line 12: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

and here is the content of the heroku.bat :

```
:: Don't use ECHO OFF to avoid possible change of ECHO
:: Use SETLOCAL so variables set in the script are not persisted
@SETLOCAL

:: Add bundled ruby version to the PATH, use HerokuPath as starting point
@SET HEROKU_RUBY="%HerokuPath%\ruby-1.9.3\bin"
@SET PATH=%HEROKU_RUBY%;%PATH%;%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Git\bin

:: Invoke 'heroku' (the calling script) as argument to ruby.
:: Also forward all the arguments provided to it.
@ruby.exe "%~dpn0" %*
```

and yes, I did try to change this file (adding and removing some ' sign) but still cannot work. Someone help me please. 
**Pakage I use: heroku toolbelt: 3.42.11** 
**windows 10 - 64bit**

thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>this happens if you use the git-bash to run heroku.bat</strike>

use a normal windows command prompt instead.

did not solve the problem :(

Comment: I tried to run from windows cmd but the prompt hangs at : `Setting up node-v4.1.1 ..... `